# String slicing and manipulation

Tags: python

Price is coming like 48600.0 however the actual price is 4.86 USD so I am doing like

```
last_price3 = str(x["last_price_4d"]) #48600.0
last_price2 = last_price3[0:1] + "." + last_price3[:-4]
last_price = float(last_price2)
```

I can do like above but what if the price has more than 1 numbers in front of the dot like 176.85 USD 
last_price_4d will be like 1768500.0

Thank you

Comment: You need to find the index of the ‘.’

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about dividing the price by 10,000 since that is how it has been scaled?

```
last_price = round(x["last_price_4d"] / 10000, 2)
```

Comment: Way more efficient than string manipulation, and just extremely straightforward

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Thank you!

Comment: Note: In case someone is still using Python 2 and `last_price_4d` could be an int instead of float in some cases, it would be safer to divide by `10000.0` (i.e. `float(10000)`) to avoid rounding errors. For example, `48600` would result in 4.0 instead of 4.86 with above code. In Python 3 this solution works fine for floats _and_ ints :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the number is scaled for being 10,000 times larger you can just divide but if you did want to do it with just string manipulation you can do

```
last_price3 = str(x["last_price_4d"])
i = last_price3.index('.')
last_price = last_price3[:i-2][:-2]+'.'+last_price3[:i-2][-2:]
```